# Enumerating formulas for Homebrew and Macports

Tags: homebrew, macports

I am trying to count the total number of homebrew formulas.  I've done a wildcard search and directed the output to a text file and counted the lines using `brew search /.*/ | wc -l`.

This produces only 3,142 formulas, 1/5 the number I found for Macports.  However, I've noticed that Macports also has a lot of duplicate packages, listing both the meta package and it's various dependent packages.  Is there a way to break out those dependent packages in Homebrew?  What about Macports, is there a way to filter out the number of redundant dependent packages?

Finally, is there a way to force Homebrew to list versions?

Comment: For Homebrew, what do you mean by "dependent packages"? Different versions?  The versions are hardcoded into the formula, there's only ever one installable version at a time.

Comment: Macports lists libgtkhtml and gtkspell as a separate entries from the GTK packages.

Answer (score 0):

You should be comparing the number of MacPorts source packages to Homebrew.  For example

```
tar tf /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar | grep Portfile | wc -l
```

Maybe there is a better way.

To get a list of package versions in Homebrew, you can try something like this:

```
for formula in $(brew search); do brew info $formula | grep "^$formula"; done
```